# Xamarin Forms: how to re-use a relative layout that was created in code?

Tags: c#, optimization, layout, xamarin.forms

I've got a relative layout which implements a row of images that have text centered over them.  Because of the text overlays, I couldn't do this with XAML and had to generate the layout in code.  This row layout appears about a dozen times on the page, and currently takes 1.5 seconds to render per row.  So I'm trying to find a way to optimize the page rendering.

What's the best approach for this type of implementation?

Is there a way to create this row layout once and re-use it for the other rows?

Comment: No there is no way to "apply" the layout to the other rows without instantiating a new one. Have you tried using a faster layout? AbsoluteLayout could fit your needs aswell. If you post a example of what you want to achieve, maybe we can give you a hint on how to do it with another layout.

Comment: Try using another layout type as Marius said, and also you can try setting the views to IsVisible = false while you are setting them up and then make them visible at the end

Comment: Imagine a row containing five Netflix rating stars, with text centered over each star -- numbers 1 through 5.  Now put a dozen of those rows on a page.  I suppose an absolute layout would work, but then wouldn't I need one for each platform?